# Keep only dataframe rows closest to given values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df1` with some variables, given for certain values A:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [110.035,110.078,110.732,112.828,112.930],
               "var1": np.random.random(5),
               "var2":np.random.random(5)})

       A          var1        var2
0   110.035     0.500537    0.571497
1   110.078     0.234550    0.732815
2   110.732     0.337149    0.098250
3   112.828     0.190261    0.366118
4   112.930     0.990539    0.892640
```

and a dataframe `df2` of values A like

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": [110.04, 112.83]})

      A
0   110.04
1   112.83
```

Now I want to keep all values in df1, that are closest to one of the values in df2 and drop all the others. In my example I want to keep rows 0 and 3 only.

My idea is to build the absolute differences and use argsort():

```
(df1.A-x).abs().argsort()[:1]
```

but this works for one value `x` only, how can I extend this to all values in df2?

Comment: `merge_asof` try look at

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `reindex` with `method='nearest'`:

```
df = df1.set_index('A').reindex(df2.A, method='nearest').reset_index()
df

        A      var1      var2
0  110.04  0.262062  0.624065
1  112.83  0.107757  0.167591
```

If you want the original `A` values back, perform a second `merge` step with `df1`:

```
df.merge(df1, on=['var1', 'var2']).reindex(columns=df1.columns)

         A      var1      var2
0  110.035  0.262062  0.624065
1  112.828  0.107757  0.167591
```

Comment: The values in column A in your output are from `df2`.  From the question it seems like the OP wants to keep the original values from `df1['A']`.

Comment: @Wen I tried merge_asof first, but couldn't seem to get it to work.... then remembered that this exists.

Comment: @coldspeed: `pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, direction='nearest')` produces the same output as your method.

Comment: @root 1) you have a point. I'll see if I can get this working. 2) I tried `pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='A', direction='nearest')` and it didn't work... I was so close :p

Answer (score 3):

Op1  `numpy.searchsorted`

Using `numpy.searchsorted` then using index slice the `df1`

```
df1.loc[np.searchsorted(df1.A, df2.A)-1]
Out[826]: 
         A      var1      var2
0  110.035  0.007591  0.768843
3  112.828  0.426480  0.902606
```

---

Op2  `merge_asof`

```
pd.merge_asof(df2,df1,on='A',direction='nearest')
Out[819]: 
        A      var1      var2
0  110.04  0.007591  0.768843
1  112.83  0.426480  0.902606
```